# Receiving media key events in Service

Tags: java, android

I know it has been explained a hundred times, and I've looked at them all and still can't figure it out. I have experience on BlackBerry 10 QT/C++ but am trying to ride the BlackBerry train into Android and that means learning both Java and the Android way of doing things.

I am following (among other guides) [this one](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/media/session/MediaButtonReceiver.html)

in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application

android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <service android:enabled="true" android:name=".myService" >
    </service>
    <receiver android:name="android.support.v4.media.session.MediaButtonReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
```

I think I have things where they need to be? No?

In myService.java

```
public class myService extends Service {
@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

private MediaSessionCompat.Callback mediaSessionCompatCallBack = new MediaSessionCompat.Callback()
{
    @Override
    public boolean onMediaButtonEvent(Intent mediaButtonEvent) {
        Log.d("MEDIAKEY", "Key Event");

        return super.onMediaButtonEvent(mediaButtonEvent);
    }
};

private MediaSessionCompat mediaSessionCompat;


@Override
public void onCreate() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "My Service Created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Log.d("SERVICE", "onCreate");

    mediaSessionCompat = new MediaSessionCompat(this, "MEDIA");


}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "My Service Stopped", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Log.d("SERVICE", "onDestroy");

}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "My Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Log.d("SERVICE_STARTUP", "onStart");

    mediaSessionCompat.setCallback(mediaSessionCompatCallBack);

    mediaSessionCompat.setFlags(MediaSessionCompat.FLAG_HANDLES_MEDIA_BUTTONS);


    MediaButtonReceiver.handleIntent(mediaSessionCompat, intent);

    mediaSessionCompat.setActive(true);


    return START_STICKY;
}
```

Any help would be great,

Thanks

EDIT:
Ok I've  changed the onCreate() to:

```
    context = getApplicationContext();

    mediaSessionCompat = new MediaSessionCompat(context, "MEDIA");

    mediaSessionCompat.setFlags(MediaSessionCompat.FLAG_HANDLES_MEDIA_BUTTONS | MediaSessionCompat.FLAG_HANDLES_TRANSPORT_CONTROLS);

    mediaSessionCompat.setCallback(new MediaSessionCompat.Callback() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMediaButtonEvent(Intent mediaButtonEvent) {
            Log.d("MEDIA", "event");

            return super.onMediaButtonEvent(mediaButtonEvent);
        }
    });
```

and onStartCommand() to:
        MediaButtonReceiver.handleIntent(mediaSessionCompat, intent);

```
    mediaSessionCompat.setActive(true);

    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
```

But still no Log.d() on pressing any media keys, I watched the video and it helped me understand it but not getting what the problem is, I'm on API 22 (5.1.1) by the way.

Comment: Don't forget to call `mediaSessionCompat.release()` in `onDestroy()` to clean up the connection.

Comment: You didn't describe, what's wrong, what error did you get, what's actual and what's expected behavior etc. The only question is if your manifest is right.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not getting a Log.d() for any play/pause or volume controls

Answer (score 2):

There's a few things in the [MediaButtonReceiver documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/media/session/MediaButtonReceiver.html) you are missing firstly:

- You need to add the `<intent-filter>` for `android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON` to your `.myService` - without this, `MediaButtonReceiver` won't know which Service to forward media buttons to
- You need to call [handleIntent()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/media/session/MediaButtonReceiver.html#handleIntent(android.support.v4.media.session.MediaSessionCompat,%20android.content.Intent)) in your [onStartCommand()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#onStartCommand(android.content.Intent,%20int,%20int))

After that, your Service will be set up correctly, but you still won't receive media buttons. As explained in the [Media Playback the Right Way talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XQwe30cZffg&t=1036), you need to become the preferred media button receiver by calling [mediaSessionCompat.setActive(true)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/media/session/MediaSessionCompat.html#setActive(boolean)).

You'll also want to make sure you are calling

```
mediaSessionCompat.setFlags(MediaSessionCompat.FLAG_HANDLES_MEDIA_BUTTONS |
  MediaSessionCompat.FLAG_HANDLES_TRANSPORT_CONTROLS);
mediaSessionCompat.setCallback(mediaSessionCompatCallBack);
```

This ensures that you say you can handle media buttons and registers your Callback instance with the MediaSessionCompat.

Note that `MediaSessionCompat` will automatically translate media buttons into the appropriate Callback methods (i.e., play will translate to `onPlay()` being called, etc) so in many cases you don't need to directly override `onMediaButtonEvent()`.

Comment: Thanks for your help
I have MediaButtonReceiver.handleIntent(mediaSessionCompat, intent); in my onStartCommand()

I also have mediaSessionCompat.setActive(true);

I added the intent-filter, and the other media transport flag, I do need to overload the buttons because i want some custom stuff going on... Still not getting the Log.d()

Comment: Then as long as you are starting your service once and add the `<intent-filter>`, it should work. As explained in the talk, generally you can `setActive(true)` when you start media playback.

Comment: I edited the original post with the changes I made, This was a lot easier on BlackBerry 10 haha. I'm not sure what I'm missing here...

Comment: @IWIK - did you also add the `<intent-filter>` to `.myService`? How are you triggering a media button? `MediaButtonReceiver` prints out an error message if it cannot find a service to forward the media button onto.

Comment: <service android:enabled="true" android:name=".myService" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action ndroid:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>

I'm just hitting the play/pause volume up, volume down. I see I actually do get a Log.d() if i connect a headset and hit the media button there, am I looking in the wrong place for volume and play/pause events?

Comment: Haha I've wasted so much time it looks like

Comment: Actually [MediaSessionCompat](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/media/session/MediaSessionCompat.html) says volume keys too...

Comment: Ah, yes volume keys are very different from media buttons: the volume keys automatically adjust the currently playing audio stream (or by default the ringer volume). You can override it by using [setPlaybackToRemote()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/media/session/MediaSessionCompat.html#setPlaybackToRemote(android.support.v4.media.VolumeProviderCompat)), but obviously that disables the user from modifying the local volume and is only appropriate if you are actually adjusting the volume on a remote device (such as with Google Cast devices).